# No sé cómo hacer esta búsqueda recursiva de vector ordenado en java

Tags: java, recursión, busqueda

El ejercicio me pide que haga una búsqueda binaria recursiva de un vector ordenador de enteros. Pero no me entero muy bien de cómo funciona este método de búsqueda.
Cuándo ejecuto el código me devuelve un 5.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int buscado = 8;
    int inf = 0;
    int sup = (vector.length - 1);
    
    System.out.print(buscarBinariaRec(vector, buscado, inf, sup));
}
```

Método:

```
static int buscarBinariaRec(int[] vector, int buscado, int inf, int sup) {
    int med = ((inf + sup) / 2);
    int aux = 0;
    
    if (inf > sup) {
        aux = -1;
    }
    
    if (buscado == vector[med]) {
        aux = med;
    }
    
    if (buscado < vector[med]) {
        aux = buscarBinariaRec(vector, inf, (med - 1), buscado);
    }
    
    if (buscado > vector[med]) {
        aux = buscarBinariaRec(vector, med + 1, sup, buscado);
    }
    
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas deben llevar el código asociado como texto, así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes de código. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error estaba en como estas pasando los parámetros a tu función, debes de seguir el mismo orden en el que lo declaraste.

```
 if (buscado < vector[med]) {
        aux = buscarBinariaRec(vector, inf, (med - 1), buscado);
    }
    
    if (buscado > vector[med]) {
        aux = buscarBinariaRec(vector, med + 1, sup, buscado);
    }
```

Puedes intentar lo siguiente. Me tomé la libertad de modificar un poco el código.

```
static int buscarBinariaRec(int[] vector, int buscado, int inf, int sup) {
        int med = (sup + inf) / 2;
        if(inf > sup) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        if(buscado == vector[med]) {
            return med;
        }
        
        else if(buscado < vector[med]){
            return buscarBinariaRec(vector, buscado, inf, med - 1);
        }
        else {
            return buscarBinariaRec(vector, buscado, med + 1, sup);
        }
    }
```

Saludos..

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Si funcionaaaaaa, buah, muchas gracias de verdad.